# Asp.net web api windows impersonation and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have asp.net mvc 4 web api site with windows authorization via Active Directory domain.
Part of it is api controller, querying sql server via entity framework.
Asp.net is tuned well - i see, that user is impersonated inside api method.
But EF queries database with anonymous credentials.

Part of web.config

```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Part of method:

```
    var winId = (WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;            
    WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
        ctx = winId.Impersonate();

        var ret = DAL.DBPort.Instance.GetDivisionStructure();
        // ret.Name = identy.AuthenticationType.ToString();
        return ret;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            ctx.Undo();
        }
    }
```

I`m constantly getting "underlying provider failed to open". 
While having impersonation, asp.net still uses anonymous or system account in database connection.
Don`t know, what to do here.

Comment: Whats the connection string to the database in your webconfig look like?  Do you specify a username and password?

Comment: No, it supposed to use Integrated security mode.

Comment: Then the logged in user probably does not have permissions to the database

Comment: No, i have rights. I`m sysadmin on server.

Comment: post the full exception with inner exception

Comment: Hidrophis,
did you check that Basic authentication is disabled and Windows integrated authentication is enabled for your web site (in IISManager)? Kind regards, Goetz